# Multiple figure caption numeration

Tags: captions

Let's say, for example, that I have 3 images:

1. Capture of a table made in Excel
2. Graph of the data in the table
3. Esquematic visual representation of whatever I'm studying

Is there a way to put as a caption in the image 1 "Table 1", on the image 2, "Graph 1" and on the image 3 "Figure 1" and make LaTeX handle the numeration of each type? By that what I want to mean is that if later I want to add another graphic, make latex put "Graph 2".

Comment: If you want one of your images to be numbered as a table, put it and its caption inside of a `table` environment instead of inside of `figure`. For the graphs, you could add `\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionType{graph}` to the preamble and place your image and its caption inside of  a `graph` environment.

Comment: You can use the newfloat package to create a graph float, complete with a `\listofgraphs`,  You can use `\captionof{graph}{...}` (caption package} to put a graph caption inside a different type of float.